# GoJS get parent Node from TextBlock click handler

Tags: javascript, gojs

Is there a way to get to the parent `Node` or the parent `GraphObject`'s in general in GoJS? I'm inside a `TextBlock` and need access to the model data in the click handler. `Panel.findObject(id)` only works from top to botton in the object hierarchy and a `TextBlock` has no access to that method either way.
I tried `diagram.findNodeForKey`, if I get access to the key from the child element, but same problem here. I thought there has to be a simple way to get to the parent `Node/Part somehow, but I didn't find any suitable function for that in the API.

As a workaround I use `diagram.selection.first().data` at the moment to get to the Node and the bound model data, it works in my case, but seems a little dirty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get to the parent Node or the parent GraphObject's in general in GoJS?

You can call [`graphobject.panel`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#panel) to get the GraphObject's panel (if it exists), or [`graphobject.part`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#part) to get the GraphObject's Part.

Comment: Thanks, `textBlock.part.data` works! I don't know how I missed those properties :D